# Angular hook pre-route change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I have an angular app that uses ngRoute for routing. The navigation bar uses `href="#/whatever"` links. I would like to stop the route from changing when the user clicks on certain links if they are not logged in. How would I hook in to the ngRoute to achieve this?

Comment: So what you have come up with?

Comment: I have no clue how to hook in to ngRoute for pre route changes.

Comment: I wrote a blog post about this here - http://jonsamwell.com/url-route-authorization-and-security-in-angular/